# What will be the groovy syntax to return null as a null object not a string in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, conditional-operator

```
BRANCH = "develop" 

BRANCH = "${BRANCH=="develop"?"null":"${BRANCH}"}"

print (BRANCH.getClass()) # class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

What is the correct syntax for null to be treated as a NUllObject?
Expecting to return class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject

Answer (score 0):

As a very minimal example to actually run as a pipeline, you can use this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Hello') {
      steps {
        script {
          def BRANCH = "develop" 
          BRANCH = "${BRANCH}" == "develop" ? null : "${BRANCH}"
          print (BRANCH.getClass())
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output looks then like this:
[image: console output]